# R - change size of axis labels with ROCR

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I want to increase the size of the axis labels. The data contains ROC curves, drawn by [ROCR](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/).

```
library(ROCR)
# load the sample data and create an performance object
data(ROCR.hiv)
pp <- ROCR.hiv$hiv.svm$predictions
ll <- ROCR.hiv$hiv.svm$labels
par(mfrow=c(2,2)) 
pred<- prediction(pp, ll)
perf <- performance(pred, measure="tpr", x.measure = "fpr")
```

Some manipulations on the figure work, others, like setting `cex.axis`, not. Here's an example:

```
# try different manipulations
plot(perf) # normal layout
plot(perf, cex.axis=2) # no change 
plot(perf, col.axis="red") # no change 
plot(perf, col.main="red", cex.main=3, main="abc") # the header may be manipulated
```

it seems like `cex.axis` is not set correctly, because

```
plot(perf, cex.axis=2) 
par()
```

shows, that

```
$cex.axis
[1] 1
```

any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: `plot(perf, cex.lab = 2)` ?

Comment: see `...` under `?plot.performance` which also has a long example "to entertain your children"

Comment: @bergant This changes the size of the axis labels. This setting is not ignored, which is good, but it is unfortunatelly not what I wanted here.

Comment: @rawr: thank you for this hint, I found the solution there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to rawr I found the answer:

```
par(cex.axis=2)
plot(perf)
```